# Generate ID based on another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I just want to produce a same code for all the blank cells follow the non-blank above cell.

[image]

[image]

Comment: VBA isn't required, though If you want to use VBA, this would be a simple for-loop. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: How far do you want to go down though? Why wouldn't you stop at `Convoy`? Surely you don't want to just drop 5 (assuming Convoy is your last value) all the way down to the last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first row of your table is populated with a value you can drop this into the 2nd row (`D4` in your photo) and drag down as needed

```
=IF(B4="",A3,A3+1)
```

---

If you did decide to go with VBA you could try this macro. Note this does not need the first row of table to be populated and the numbering will stop at the last value found in the `Type` column

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim xCell As Range

For Each xCell In ws.Range("A3:A" & ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If xCell.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
        xCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("A3:A" & xCell.Row)) + 1
    Else
        xCell = xCell.Offset(-1)
    End If
Next xCell

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

You can try using a simple `COUNTIF` approach:

`=COUNTIF($B$3:B3,"<>"&"")`

[image]

This will count how many Solo/Convoys are not blank in a given range. For column E, use `=B3&""` to copy the values from column B.

Comment: Why `COUNTIF` if the result can be obtained by just looking at the current row and one row above? Seems like overkill.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman, that would be even easier but then I thought what if there are more than one or two blank rows (having no Solo/Convoy value). Then checking the current row and the one above won't do the trick. Unless you had some other solution in mind?

Comment: When you copy a formula down, either a given cell is blank, in which case the count is not incremented, or it is non-blank, in which case it is increased by 1. In formula pseudocode:  `=If(check for blank, value above, 1 + value above)`

Comment: It won't work for the first row (D3) so it'd need to have an additional condition or a check.
I guess there are lots of correct approaches here and the visible difference in performance will only show when OP starts working on larger datasets :-)

Comment: It is partly a matter of taste, but you are correct that my (rough) idea would need to be booted-up in the first row. Under the hood, your solution is quadratic in the number of rows, hence might lag for large data sets.

Comment: Thank you @JohnColeman for your support, It worked on non-tabular format. However, I use a tabular format, So how can I adjust this formula to work in this environment.